# Problem with port forwarding eth0 > ppp0

Tags: iptables

I am having a server with public IP (eth0 : IP: 1.2.3.4) and having in the same way a VPN connection (ppp0: 10.20.20.20), when I am doing telnet in the server:

```
root@vps:/# telnet 10.20.20.20 25
Trying 10.20.20.20...
Connected to 10.20.20.20.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 mail.mail.com
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

---

route table:

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0         U     0      0        0 ppp0
```

Which is connected successfully without any issues, what I am trying to do is to forward all the incoming port 25 from eth0 IP: 1.2.3.4 directly to port 25 in ppp0.

Using iptables:

```
-A PREROUTING -d 1.2.3.4 -p tcp --dport 25 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.20.20.20:25
-A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

I am seeing the port still closed with no connection, the telnet work in the server itself, but not through port forwarding by incoming connection from eth0

does I am missing something?

looking forward.

Comment: is forwarding enabled: `cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward` ?

Comment: yes it is , actually it is working without ppp , only when connect to the VPN not works.